# Scale many images on browser size (CSS / jQuery ?)

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, image-scaling

I have a little web project. On this page i have some images with the same size (360x270 pixel). I want to scale the images in the right size for the viewport of the browserwindow. A sample will demonstrate what i mean.  I hope anybody can help me. Here a link to the demonstration site.

http://oscar-charlie.de/#/clients

On my page, i have two lines with three images. I don't know a solution to scale the images proportional with the browser size. My first idea based on jquery or css3.

Comment: You could use CSS percentage sizes. If the container of the images is the width/height of the window then your images could have a width of 33.3% or something like that. Then they would scale with the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this to resize your images when the window is resized:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $(".item img").css({"width": $(window).width()/3, "height": "auto"});
    $(".item").css({"width": $(".item img").width(), "heigt": $(".item img").height()});
});
```

But still you will have problems filling exactly the height or the width of the window keeping the right proportion.

Comment: I had this idea at the beginning, but the problem is the proportional scaling. ok, i can calculate this with javascript - scalefactor and so one, but is here not a easier way?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
.classforimages {
    width:33%;
    max-width:360px;
    height:auto;
}
```

This will make the image take up 33% of its parent, to a maximum of 360px width.

Comment: The images on the site he was referring to don't change according to the windows width but according to the windows height. So it should be `height: XX%; width: auto;`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with [`media-queries`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/):

```
/* Normal behavior: 4 images */
.your-img {
    height: 25%;
    width: auto;
}
/* If the browser window is 800px high: 3 images */
@media (max-height:800px) {
    .your-img {
        height: 33.3%
    }
}
/* If the browser window is 600px high: 2 images */
@media (max-height:600px) {
    .your-img {
        height: 50%
    }
}
/* If the browser window is 400px high: 1 image */
@media (max-height:400px) {
    .your-img {
        height: 100%
    }
}
```

Here is a quick and dirty [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vWjsZ/1/)

Also have a look at this excellent resources:

[developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries)

[www.smashingmagazine.com](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)